# Using the shell provided with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, require, node-modules

Once you've installed NodeJS, you'll have a executable in your computer named **NodeJS** which is a shell. I was wondering what can I do with that... here you're able to run JS code as, for example, in the browser's console, great.

Now, is it possible to **require modules** in that env? Doing so, I'd be able to run some JS code using functions provided by those modules which IMO would be really, really great.

I've tried installing the modules with the `-g` option (for example `npm install -g express`); then (in that shell) I want to run `require('express')` but it doesen't work, it says:

`Error: Cannot find module 'express' 
    at Function.Module._resolveFileName ...`

Ideas?

Comment: run in `cmd`: `npm ls` and `npm root` and `npm list -g` show us ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [issue #5431](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5431), looks like the Node.JS REPL doesn't find globally-installed modules and this is expected behaviour.

In the [article linked from that issue](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/), it reads:

> 1. If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of your project.

This is your case, sou need to install `express` *locally*:

```
$ npm install express
$ node
> var express = require('express');
undefined
```

Note that you get `undefined` as a result because of the `var` statement, but it did work.

Comment: should not refer to this issue. It s a normal behavior. global is just another context within what the versions are evaluated in a non conflcting way. As of the local module is another context.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a directory, then run `npm install express --save`, then `node`, and finally `var express = require('express');`

Answer (score 0):

Answers above are correct. Just want to add another point: going to the folder where the executable is, you'll find there the directory `node_modules`

```
nodejs
|-------node_modules
|        |-----------npm
|-------node
|-------more staff
```

If you paste any folder of a module inside `node_modules` it'll be able to be required in the nodeJS shell.

Anyway, I prefer the other solution instead to `CTR-C + CTRL-V`.

Comment: yeah it will work fine between two empty ptoject. But if you paste between existing projects, you may face versions misatch. Which is what npm is made to fight. The good way is to use npm. Note ```--save``` to help you to do that right. Also if you want to faster your install you can think about using ```sinopia```, it s local cache.